# Combine two tables with same columns but different values and return only the not machting ones

Tags: sql, oracle

I have tables with the same columns but the values are not all the same. I want to see the values from the columns that dont exists in table 1 but exists in table 2.

it works with:

```
select *
from table_1
where not exists (select * from table_2 where table_1.xxx = table_2.xxx)
```

and I join the rest of the columns on each other.

But isn't there a faster way then join every column in the not exists?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question says *"I want to see the values from the columns that dont exists in table 1 but exists in table 2"*, however your code example is getting you all rows in `table_1` where the same row *doesn't* exist in `table_2`.  So, not knowing which one you want, I present you with this solution, which gives you what you asked for first.  If you want it the other way around, swap the table names:

```
select * from table_2
minus
select * from table_1
```

Caveats:

1. Tables must have exactly the same schema.
2. If you're not sure about the schema, or the tables may change over time you could specify columns in the select statements, but only the specified columns will be matched.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! EXPECT doesnt work for me (using Oracle) but instead i should use MINUS. That worked! TY!

Comment: Tagging _oracle_ would have been a nice additional information to your question ;-)

Comment: I've updated my answer, if it's useful please upvote as well. Also please don't use answers instead of comments, if you have something to say related to the question or an answer, just add a comment under the relevant section. Please can delete this answer to clean things up for the next person who has the same question. Thanks and I hope you enjoy contributing to SO!